# how activate qgis features selection toolbar in the main window

Tags: qgis, python, toolbar

How can i activate and desactivate qgis features selection toolbar in the main window using a signal in a python plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can activate the "Select Single Feature" tool using `iface.actionSelect().trigger()`.

If you want to be able to deactivate the tool, you need to activate the tool that was previously active. You can save the active tool using

```
currentTool = iface.mapCanvas().mapTool()
```

Then, when you want to deactivate the "Select Single Feature" tool, you can activate the previous tool using

```
currentTool.activate()
```